# Modify column value in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, replace

I have a column with array datatype.Below is the data

```
  col1
{1001,23,SAM}
{2001,34,AS}
```

I am trying to replace ',' with '-' and also store the data in square brackets instead of {}

```
  col1
[1001-23-SAM]
[2001-34-AS]
```

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces or commas aren't actually stored. It's just the default display format for arrays in Postgres, so you can't really change that.

But you can *display* the array differently when selecting it:

```
select concat('[', array_to_string(col1, '-'), ']')
from the_table;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MCWKPM72656

Comment: It throws ERROR: function concat(unknown, text, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @user8545255: what is your Postgres version?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you are using a version earlier than 9.4

```
select '[' || array_to_string(col1, '-') || ']' from your_table;
```